# macOS, changing the size of a view controller by dragging

Tags: macos, cocoa, mouseevent, nsview, nsviewcontroller

The user clicks a button and I present a new viewController as `show`.

Inside that VC there is a `AVPlayerView`, the same size as the VC.

The app itself can change size if the user drags any of its corners but the VC displaying the movie cannot.

Why things like that that should work by default, don't work as expected? What can be done to make this work?

Example:

This is the main app.

[image]

I can drag its corners and make it bigger or small. I can click on the green semaphore and make it full screen and it works fine.

[image]

When I press the `Help` icon, this "window" appears. It is a viewController that was added the story board.

This cannot be scaled. It "appears" to be a window, because it contains a semaphore. I cannot scale this but I can make it full screen by the green semaphore.

---

Note: I have added the view to a `WindowController` and now when the user presses the `Help` button this window controller is launched and the video appears. No change. Video cannot be scaled.

Comment: Your question would be clearer with screenshots and more thorough explanations.

Comment: I have added more info to the question. Thanks.

Comment: FYI, it's not a "semaphore," it's just a button, specifically the window's zoom button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem.

1. I had to add a window controller controlling that View Controller.

View controller was not resizing even after #1.

Then I found that I could not have

```
self.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: 940,height: 504)
```

inside `awakeFromNib`.

Now it works perfectly.

Answer (score -1):

"The app itself can change size" –– what you're saying is that the *window* can be resized by the user.

"but the VC displaying the movie cannot" –– Again in this case, you're not trying to resize a view controller, you're trying to resize a *window*. The window contains your view controller.

The reason the window can't be resized is probably due to the layout constaints. I imagine there must be constraints somewhere in the view hierarchy which specifies that the video player (or some other view) has a specific width and height. Because it's a constant value, the window can't resize.

Comment: I have added more info to the question. Thanks.